# Show different data in Jquery plot graph tooltip

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

I am using jquery flot charts. I want to show real data in tooltip.
It shows me Y axis data only.On a vertical Line,if there is two types of data each one is 50(total=100).

First portion is showing 50 but upper portion is showing 100.It should show 50 also as 100-50.

here is my code for this logic.

```
var options1 = {
series: {stack: stack,
         lines: { show: lines, fill: false, steps: steps },
         bars: { show: bars, barWidth: 0.4 },
         points: { show: true}
         },
         grid: {
  hoverable: true //IMPORTANT! this is needed for tooltip to work
    },
 tooltip: true,
 tooltipOpts: {
 content: "%s : %y", 
 shifts: {
   x: -60,
   y: 25
    }
 },
    legend:{'position':'ne','show':true,'margin':[-3, -20],'backgroundOpacity':0.1, 'noColumns': 4, 'container': null},
        xaxis: {ticks: dest4 ,},

};
```

what can i do with this line

```
content: "%s : %y",
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qbXDw/16/

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think I misunderstood your question? If this is not what you wanted, just ignore it (or comment and I will remove it). I thought you wanted the name of the category in the tooltip.

---

You can give the `content` property a function which gets the right category name from the `dest3` array:

```
content: function(label, xval, yval, flotItem) {
    var category = dest3.filter(function (item) { return item[0] == xval })[0][1];
    return label + ' : ' + category + ' : ' + yval;
},
```

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qbXDw/17/).